# Forcing datatype for hdf5 file using h5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have a csv file which has "Date","Time" and other columns (10 or so)

```
Date,Time,C
20020515,123000000,10293
20020515,160000000,10287
20020516,111800000,10270
20020516,160000000,10260
20020517,130500000,10349
20020517,160000000,10276
20020520,123700000,10313
20020520,160000000,10258
20020521,114500000,10223
```

I am trying to load this into a hdf5 file and have Date and Time type be "String" and not integer32. So I am doing this

```
import h5py,numpy as np
my_data = np.genfromtxt("/tmp/data.txt",delimiter=",",dtype=None,names=True)
myFile="/tmp/data.h5"
with h5py.File(myFile,"a") as f:
  dset = f.create_dataset('foo',data=my_data)
```

I would like to store "Date" and "Time" as type "String" on HDF5. Not Int32.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. According to the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html): `Datasets are very similar to NumPy arrays. They are homogenous collections of data elements, with an immutable datatype and (hyper)rectangular shape.` This means that all columns must have the same `dtype`.

Comment: Do you want to change the way that you are *storing* the data in the HDF5 file, or do you want to be able to convert those columns to strings after reading them from the file?

Comment: I want to change the way I am storing the data. I want to store them as String instead of integer.

Answer (score 6):

One simple solution would be to change the dtype of `my_data` before writing it to the file:

```
newtype = np.dtype([('Date', 'S8'), ('Time', 'S8'), ('C', '<i8')])
dset2 = f.create_dataset('foo2', data=my_data.astype(newtype))
```

You could also create an empty dataset by passing the appropriate `dtype=` and `shape=` parameters to `f.create_dataset`, then fill in the values from `my_data`:

```
dset3 = f.create_dataset('foo3', shape=my_data.shape, dtype=newtype)
dset3[:] = my_data.astype(newtype)
```

Note that I still have to cast `my_data` to `newtype` before writing it - h5py doesn't seem to be able to handle the type conversion itself:

```
In [15]: dset3[:] = my_data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-6e62dae3d59a> in <module>()
----> 1 dset3[:] = my_data

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-build-aayglkf0/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2579)()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-build-aayglkf0/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2538)()

/home/alistair/.venvs/core3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in __setitem__(self, args, val)
    584         mspace = h5s.create_simple(mshape_pad, (h5s.UNLIMITED,)*len(mshape_pad))
    585         for fspace in selection.broadcast(mshape):
--> 586             self.id.write(mspace, fspace, val, mtype)
    587 
    588     def read_direct(self, dest, source_sel=None, dest_sel=None):

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-build-aayglkf0/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2579)()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-build-aayglkf0/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2538)()

h5py/h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.write (/tmp/pip-build-aayglkf0/h5py/h5py/h5d.c:3421)()

h5py/_proxy.pyx in h5py._proxy.dset_rw (/tmp/pip-build-aayglkf0/h5py/h5py/_proxy.c:1794)()

h5py/_proxy.pyx in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dwrite (/tmp/pip-build-aayglkf0/h5py/h5py/_proxy.c:1501)()

OSError: Can't prepare for writing data (No appropriate function for conversion path)
```